# How to think of Normalizers in a 1-object category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm learning introductory category theory and stumbled upon the notion that a group is essentially a one-object category where every arrow is invertible. Then it follows the centralizer of the group is nothing more than the natural transformations Id => Id.

I'm wondering if we can frame the normalizer in similar categorical language?
I don't see how to relax the conditions of a natural transformation so that we don't have a commuting diagram for every element, but a sort of "commuting diagram as a whole". Are we looking for a natural transformation between functors other than Id?

Comment: The normalizer of what? What is $A$ in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question so that nobody wastes time responding:
A normalizer is a natural transformation Hom(A,-) => Hom(A,-) (I believe)